# Needing to bind 2 jquery files

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to do my ajax for a form I have but when I try to make form submit without refreshing the page, it doesn't work because I have a default jquery / javascript that came with the theme I'm using that's overwriting the jquery I'm calling. I need the one that came with the theme because it does most of my functions and adds the style to my site.

Specifically, my side bar slider navigation is corrupt as it's showing the side bar before I click open and it won't let me close it.

[HERE IS A PICTURE OF THE SIDE BAR](https://gyazo.com/7e9a2d1dbf6d370b11ba0f49059d0374)

I usually open/close it by pressing the 3 dots underneath each other at the top.

But by using the jquery.js from the library that support AJAX, it makes my navigation / side bar go like this.

I need to somehow pick out what's causing the problem / make my own one with the correct AJAX.

Could anyone help me to find the problem that's causingthis ?

***My jquery / js file that came with the theme (the one working with the sidebar but not the AJAX - The files were too large for pastebin) :***

[LINK TO THEME JS / JQUERY FILE](https://www.sendspace.com/file/6hxziq)

***My jquery file that Allows AJAX but makes the sidebar not work correcty :***

[LINK TO JQUERY LIBRARY'S JQUERY FILE](https://www.sendspace.com/file/dmg6ws)

Comment: don't post links to files, its not feasible for someone who would want to help you, post the code here itself.

Comment: if you have large files, provide a working piece of code that would reproduce your issue

Comment: @Nagaraju you make no sense. How would I post all the code here if it would go way beyond the characters allowed... ?

Comment: did my second comment make any sense for you? if there is no code in your question and I am sure it will be unanswered because it doesn't make any sense to people here

Comment: @Nagaraju I provided links to my .js files with the code in as the code was too large to upload.

Comment: you are again saying the same thing, provide a working example no one is going to search your entire code to track your issue